# azure app service authentication/authorization not available

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I am attempting to set up the authentication for a Google login in my Azure App Service.

However In my App Service the 'Authentication/Authorization' section is not available.

What do I need to do to enable this???

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it seems you are based on Linux Consumption plan (because only this host plan doesn't support authentication/authorization feature).

The solution is give your function app another host plan, such as Linux Premium plan.

This is the official document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad

[image]

If you use Linux Consumption plan, then any way of authentication/authorization is impossible.